# fatal error: mysql/services.h: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, c, linux

In performing `#include <mysql/plugin.h>` in my test app im getting rather the error  `: fatal error: mysql/services.h: No such file or directory` im I supposed to link against a library? or do I have to install some other library?
Im using gcc to compile on Ubuntu 14

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC plugin.c
```

is the compile command

Comment: you need to tell the compiler about the `path` to the header file. you can use `-I` switch with gcc

Answer (score 1):

Add the option `-I/usr/include/mysql/` to your build command.

Comment: Im trying to install  a mysql test plugin using the syntax `INSTALL PLUGIN` plugin_name SONAME 'path_to_shared_object' but i get the Error: 

    ERROR 1124 (HY000): No paths allowed for shared library

Running Ubuntu 14 LTS

Comment: @Dario: This is another question, please pose it as such.